# How to dynamically map data from multiple source formats?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem where I receive multiple CSV files with the same data columns but each file has a unique format / column names.  There are several hundred files and this will continue to grow, so mapping each one manually isn't an option.  Is there a good way to search each file to dynamically map its data to the master DB? The data consists of several fields of text and numeric types.

Comment: If you can show a good samples that will help a lot ! Also, what kind of machine is receiving that data and how?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide samples due to the sensitivity of data.  However what we are trying to do is have users submit their system specific generated reports to us via a website, which we will parse and store in our database.  We are trying to avoid forcing a standard template to make it easier on the user.

Comment: The issue with that is, that if that data comes in different orders you will mix up the results at the end, specially if the fields themselves don't have a specific format!, if they do have then you just need to parse them to detect what kind of field is it and you can generate the insert template dynamically, but if not!! your template is the best way to go!

Comment: oh wait a second, you are putting that those fields have a unique format!, if the data comes like that, then it is not a big deal. The machine getting the data should be able to parse them. As we don't know what kind of machine is, I cannot say if scripting will make it, or maybe a c parser, I have a similar scenario when I get data from different sources, so what I do is read them all with a C parser I created that generated a formatted output for the data insertion to the DB, but as I said, it depends on your infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks, Marco!  Yes, it will use a script to parse the data.  Determining types is a good thought and will probably get us most of the way.  Any suggestions for determining which text field is a name vs a description?

Comment: I have a couple of examples in a ksh script, the first I would do in your case is setting up the logic. For example: Names are "usually" firstname+" "+lastname and firstname+" "+lastname+" "+2ndLastname (For hispanic names), the average first name is 3-10, lastname and 2ndlastname 3-10, so there you can add some initial logic to get the names, BUT now you have to exclude some other from that previous list, if those are descriptions then #1, they are even larger, will include chars like "\s{tT}he\s", "\sins", "\sof\s" and several combinations of the previous ones, but requires some testing.